# How to set geo_point type in elasticsearch, kibana, logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to set geo_point type from csv files which have latitude and longitude using logstash. But I really don't know how to convert latitude and longitude to location(geo_point type). I'm using logstash for this, but it seems that there is not enough information about it.
I found this way.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/Users/"name"/Downloads/coronavirusdataset_20200601/Case.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    #sincedb_path => "/dev/null"    
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["case_id","province","city","group","infection_case","confirmed","latitude","longitude"]
  }
  mutate {convert => ["latitude", "float"]}
  mutate {convert => ["longitude", "float"]}
  mutate {convert => ["confirmed", "float"]}
  mutate {rename => ["latitude", "[location][lat]"]}
  mutate {rename => ["longitude", "[location][lon]"]}
output {  
    elasticsearch {
        template => "/Users/"name"/Downloads/logstash-7.7.1/config/elasticsearch-template.json"
        template_overwrite => true
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        user => "user-name"
        password => "password"
        workers => 1
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

and this is my elasticsearch-template.json.

```
{
    "template" : "logstash-*",
    "settings" : {
      "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "_default_" : {
        "_all" : {"enabled" : true, "omit_norms" : true},
        "dynamic_templates" : [ {
          "message_field" : {
            "match" : "message",
            "match_mapping_type" : "string",
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
              "fielddata" : { "format" : "disabled" }
            }
          }
        }, {
          "string_fields" : {
            "match" : "*",
            "match_mapping_type" : "string",
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
              "fielddata" : { "format" : "disabled" },
              "fields" : {
                "raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "ignore_above" : 256}
              }
            }
          }
        } ],
        "properties" : {
          "@timestamp": { "type": "date" },
          "@version": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
          "geoip"  : {
            "dynamic": true,
            "properties" : {
              "ip": { "type": "ip" },
              "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" },
              "latitude" : { "type" : "float" },
              "longitude" : { "type" : "float" }
            }
          },
    "location" : { "type": "geo_point" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have kept on trying to figure out the problem, and I found a way using kibana dev tools. I also changed my logstash conf file not using elasticsearch-template.json I have used above. I just use like below.

```
mutate {rename => ["latitude", "[location][lat]"]}
mutate {rename => ["longitude", "[location][lon]"]}
```

Here is the way to solve problem using kibana dev tools, but it didn't work anyway.

```
PUT _template/geo-test
{
  "order: 0,
  "index_patterns": "geo-test",
  "mappings": {
    "_defaults_": {
      "properties": {
          "location": {
             "type":  "geo_point"
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```